# Why code comes different result from VC6.0 and Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, codeblocks

I want to delete repeated adjacent characters like this:
input:goooggllee
output:gogle

VC6.0 gives the result I want: gogle.

while code::blocks comes some strange character followed,

such as: gogle '$ ♦.
just strange marks. 
Following is program.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

void deleteRepeatChar(char *instr,char *outstr)
{
    char *p=instr;
    *outstr=*p;
    ++outstr;
    while(*p){
        char *q=p;
        while(*(q+1)==*(outstr-1))  // compare with the former char
            ++q;
        if(q>p){
            *outstr=*(q+1);
            ++outstr;
            p=q+1;
        }
        else{
            ++p;
            *outstr=*p;
            ++outstr;
        }
    }
    *outstr='\0';  
}                  

int main()
{
    const int sz=100;
    char str[]="gooooggllle";
    char out[sz];
    deleteRepeatChar(str,out);
    for(auto &c:out)
        cout<<c;
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for(auto &c:out) will iterate through all 100 characters, it won't stop at the terminating nul character

Comment: VC6.0 is an old an even non-standard compliant compiler. If you are using some other compiler with Code Blocks, thats the reason because both output different results.

Comment: There's no way this code compiled in VC6.

Comment: How can VC6.0 even compile the range-based `for` loop? That's a C++11 feature.

Comment: @FredLarson: I don't think VC6 would even compile the C++98 features (e.g. `<iostream>` instead of `<iostream.h>`), let alone the C++11.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Yes, VC6 did handle `<iostream>`.

Comment: Unless you really want to do this yourself, consider using `std::unique`, which is designed for precisely the operation you seem to want.

Comment: Did you compile your code in DEBUG mode in VC? Try running it in RELEASE and I think you'll get weird characters in your VC output as well. And to make your code work, as jcoder said, just remove the `for` loop and output using `std::cout << out;`.

Comment: Thank you guys, I just did not really understand iterator.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jerry Coffin said using std::unique is the way to go. conceptually it iterates through the string and every time it finds to sequential characters it moves the remainder of the string towards the beginning. Because the null termination is not removed by std::unique there is no need to worry about it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    char str[]="gooooggllle";
    std::unique(std::begin(str),std::end(str));
    std::cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

or live at: http://ideone.com/WEZ0Zk is an example of how to use it.

It is quite probably faster to change the string in place than to make a copy with the changed string, however if you do want the modified string to be copied into a new string you can use std::unique_copy

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    char str[]="gooooggllle";
    char out[sizeof(str)];
    std::unique_copy(std::begin(str),std::end(str),std::begin(out));
    std::cout << out;
    return 0;
}
```

For more information on std::unique see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique

It is, in my opinion, good practice to use standard algorithms as often as possible in code because it not only can save you time and run faster and save you countless bugs but of most importance - it allows other people to understand your code quickly. There are some prominent people, for example Sean Parent from Adobe, who say whenever your write a for loop you are doing something wrong, there is always an algorithm which will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks.It is the best way.